# How to open another app from ionic app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I want to open an app in my phone from my ionic app. Along with that I want to send some data(as given below) too. I want to do this using uri scheme. URI for

Android:
someapp://com.example.example/?someField=someData

iOS:
someapp://?someField=someData

I have triend this but it's not working:

```
var browserRef = this.inAppBrowser.create(
        "twitter://com.twitter.android",
        "_system",
        "location=no,hidden=no,zoom=no"
);
```

however when i use url as https://twitter.com like below, it's working just fine.

```
var browserRef = this.inAppBrowser.create(
        'https://twitter.com',
        "_system",
        "location=no,hidden=no,zoom=no"
      );
```

but I can't use the http link as I want to send data in above specified format. Please help!!

My system configuration is:

```
    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.12.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.12.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.0.1

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.12
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1

System:

    Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
    Node              : v8.6.0
    npm               : 4.6.1
    OS                : macOS Sierra
    Xcode             : Xcode 8.3.3
```

Comment: Have you tried [this approach](http://digitalrepublic.ro/how-to-launch-external-social-media-applications-with-ionic-2/)?

Comment: try this it works for me https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/launch-or-install-third-party-apps-from-with-in-ionic-app/38419

Comment: it worked...Thank you @MustafaLokhandwala

Comment: Glad that it helps you !!

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this in your config.xml.

```
<access origin="someapp:*" launch-external="yes" />
```

Add this in your Whitelist, is needed to launch external application.